# Why did the horse keep on walking when Glass was not on it?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-revenant

During the scene in *The Revenant* where Glass tricked Fitzgerald by setting up his commander's body on his horse, why did the horse keep on walking? Doesn't the horse need to be signaled in order to keep going?

Answer (score 5):

Most likely the horse was trained and it still felt the weight of the dead body thinking there is still someone on top of it. It is also possible that Glass could have used the rope that tied the two horses together to signal.